# Apache POI Powerpoint, XMLSlideShow.createChart() not found

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, powerpoint, javadoc

I'm currently working with Apache POI, creating PowerPoint reports automatically.
I've been trying to add a `Chart` to the `PowerPoint`.

In the documentation for `Apache POI` there is a method called `XMLSlideShow.createChart()` which can't be found in the lib when trying to use it.

The project is set up with Maven, I am currently using `Apache POI 3.17.`

Am I not using the right version or is `createChart()` not implemented yet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide the complete stacktrace.

Comment: It doesn't compile since the method doesn't exist.

Error:(65, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createChart(org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide)
  location: variable show of type org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation of Apache POI is updated regularly during development, the method is being implemented for a future release.

The documentation for the version I'm using isn't online but downloaded with the lib.